# Needs some light on c99 Bit Field explanation

Tags: c, c99, bit-fields

I am reading gnu c99 manual and it has mentioned:

> Bit fields can be specified without a name in order to control which
>   actual bits within the containing unit are used. However, the effect
>   of this is not very portable and it is rarely useful. You can also
>   specify a bit field of size 0, which indicates that subsequent bit
>   fields not further bit fields should be packed into the unit
>   containing the previous bit field. This is likewise not generally
>   useful.

I am not able to appreciate it can anyone help me to understand it.

Comment: What part of this do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: I am unable to understand what does above mean and how to test it. Can you explain it will the help of example? Like what does it mean specifying bit field without name ?? What are the meaning of other statements?

Comment: As I am learning by my own and nobody is for help except  SO

Comment: A bitfield simply allows you to declare a struct containing, say an `unsigned int` (32-bits total) and then designate (name) several variables that are associated with a range of bits within the total 32 that they represent. You can then set or reference those individual bits though the 'name' associated with them. For example say you have an encoded date, where the first 5-bits represent the day, the next 4-bits represent the month, and the final 14-bits the year (23-bits total), you could declare `struct datefld {unsigned short day : 5, month : 4, year : 14; };`

Comment: Wikipedia a decent article with examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: @David C.Rankin things have started making sense ... Thanks

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The unit used for bit-fields is implementation-defined, even if `unsigned int` is specified, and it is implementation-defined whether `unsigned short` (which is likely not what you want for 23 bits) or anything other yhan `_Bool`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int` is allowed.

Comment: Agree, the most important part of the quoted paragraph is *"However, the effect of this is not very portable and it is rarely useful."*